# Stationary graphic frame around web page content

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

I'm trying to create a graphic frame around the content of a web page that will remain stationary as the content within scrolls.

http://nosgoth.net/NR-Test/ff_scroll-test3.html

Here, you can see that I've gotten the top and sides of the frame to remain stationary, by the bottom still scrolls.  Is there a way the make the bottom of the frame fix to the bottom of a browser window, regardless of the window's height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your `.framebtm` element fixed to the bottom of your page?

```
.framebtm {
  height: 71px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

But add some `padding-bottom` on your `.content` element, otherwise you won't be able to see the last line of text